# Plot multiple functions with log axis on Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I want to plot two functions on the same graph using a log y axis on Wolfram Alpha, but I can't find a way to do this.

I've tried things like `log plot 2^(3x-1), e^x, x=1..10`, but this doesn't work (despite `plot 2^(3x-1), e^x, x=1..10` working perfectly fine).

Comment: Fantastic, that works - thanks! Want to add it as an answer? I also posted the question here if you'd like to answer it there as well: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111883/171236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  logplot {2^(3x-1), e^x}, (x, 1, 10)
```

Here it is as a link on [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logplot+%7B2%5E(3x-1),+e%5Ex%7D,+(x,+1,+10))

Here it is as a Mathematica command

```
  LogPlot[{2^(-1 + 3*x), E^x}, {x, 1, 10}, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed["Expressions", Above], ImageSize -> Large]
```

Here is the output

[image]