# Wolfram alpha plot of a piecewise function with 2 domains.

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha, piecewise-continuity

So, Wolfram Alpha is capable of plotting [two functions in one figure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523163/661219).

But I am trying to express a piecewise function that has a different form on two (touching) domains.

In C code:

```
x < pi ? cos(pi/2 + x/2) : cos(x) // for x 0..2pi
```

I tried things like:

```
plot cos(pi/2 + x/2) and cos(y) for x=0 to pi and y=pi to 6.28
```

...but whatever I try, I can't make it plot piecewise?

I also tried the mathematical notation for conditions using the `|` notation, to no avail.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to plot?  I cannot quite make out the "computer code" Is that code (what language, C?) or pseudocode?

Comment: Do you want to plot a piecewise function?  $f = \cos(\pi/2+x/2)$ when $(0<x<\pi)$ and $f=\cos(x),$ whe $ (\pi \le x < 2\pi) $

Comment: @mjw Thanks. Yes, exactly that. I've added the piecewise term to my question. I think I confused partial with piecewise.

Comment: I advise you to post this question on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Cos[\[Pi]/2 + x/2], x < \[Pi]}, {Cos[x], x >= \[Pi]}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, None}, {{0, Pi/2, Pi, (3 Pi)/2, 2 Pi}, None}}, 
GridLines -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, (3 Pi)/2, 2 Pi}, {-1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1}}]
```

[image]

The function plotted is

$$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} \cos (x/2+\pi/2), \quad &(0<x<\pi)\\  \cos(x), \quad &(\pi \le x < 2\pi).  \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So the piecewise keyword is what matters here. Note that your notation is not accepted by Wolfram Alpha for being too long. I guess you need a PRO account to see it.

Comment: You are welcome!   Sorry about that, in *Mathematica*, there is plenty of room to get fancy.  The main point is to produce a piecewise plot.  This works in Wolfram $\alpha$:    Plot[Piecewise[{{Cos[\[Pi]/2 + x/2], x < \[Pi]}, {Cos[x], x >= \[Pi]}}],{x,0,2Pi}]

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7BCos%5B%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2+%2B+x%2F2%5D%2C+x+%3C+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%2C+%7BCos%5Bx%5D%2C+x+%3E%3D+%5C%5BPi%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2Pi%7D%5D